# Connection management mqtt broker kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, session, mqtt, mosquitto

We are using `Mosquitto` MQTT broker, an IoT server implementation and devices which connect to the Broker as an Client. Both device and IoT server will be publishing to the broker.

The devices publish requests to the topic : `/req/<device-id>/<server-id>`

The devices subscribe to responses : `/resp/<device-id>/<server-id>`

And if IoT server sends a notification to a particular device, it publish  to  notification topic to which device also subscribes:

```
/req/<server-id>/<device-id>
```

[image]

So this scenario is working fine uptill now, but we want to shift our implementation on `Kubernetes` such that both MQTT broker and IoT server will have multiple pods running.

So now any device can connect to any `mosquitto` pod instance and any `IoT server` pod would be connecting to `mosquitto` pod instance.

So a device connected to `mosquitto` pod1 and `IoT server` pod1 might not receive notifications if pod2 of `IoT server` generates notification and sends it to `mosquitto` pod instance to which our device wasn't connected to.

So `IoT server` will need the awareness that which `device` is connected to which pod instance to send notifications.

How to achieve this in `Kubernetes` environment??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to this is: You don't easily.

The longer answer is:

You will probably need to pick a different MQTT broker than mosquitto, mosquitto does not support clustering, so there is no (simple) way to run multiple instances that sessions and messages can be distributed across.

You can setup bridging between multiple broker instances to ensure messages end up on all instances, but the best way to do this is with a star formation, with a "central" broker that then redistributes all the messages to the points of the star. The devices would then connect to the these star instances. This does not solve any of the problems with distributed sessions.

You will also probably need to look at shared subscriptions so that messages are only consumed by a single instance of the IoT Server.

There are several other MQTT broker implementations that support proper clustering, iirc things like HiveMQ and emqx

Comment: Will Solace be a better choice as compared to HiveMQ ? Also, in open source VernMQ be a better choice over EMQx ?

Comment: I'm not going to comment on which may be best for your specific situation, I just suggested some broker implementations that I beleive support clustering